# How to generate css with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i am working on the button generator and last step is to generate the css code for the div which is my button. i am using the code below but w can only store one value let say for the width how can i get another values for height padding etc..?

```
function showWidth(ele, w) {
    $("#myCode").html(  "width:"   + w + ";"  + "<br/>" + " height: "   + w + ";" + "<br/>");
}

$("#code").click(function () { 
    showWidth("button", $("#valuePX").val()); 
    showWidth("button", $("#valuePX1").val()); 
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery's CSS method.

```
buttonHeight = $("button").css("height");
buttonPadding = $("button").css("padding");
```

You can use this method for any CSS property.

And if you need to set the value:

```
buttonHeight = $("button").css("height","100px");
buttonPadding = $("button").css("padding","0 50 0 25");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showWidth(ele, values) {
      $("#myCode").html(  "width:"   + values.width + ";"  + "<br/>" + " height: "   + values.height + ";" + "<br/>" 

);
    }
    $("#code").click(function () { 
        var values = {};
        values.width = $("#valuePX").val();
        values.height = $("#valuePX1").val();
       //you can add as many things as possible like values.padding, values.anything
        showWidth("button",values); 

});
```